Is the creation of local weaviate server from ground up necessary every time I restart the server?
I have a local weaviate server running. I ingest my data in it and can use it for similarity search usecases
The process is

Define an embeddings model using langchain
Ingest the data in the weaviate local client. This includes passing the data through the embedding model
Use it in similarity search

However, whenever I take down the service with docker compose down or restart the VM I have to do all three steps again. Is that entirely necessary? Can I do better? Presently it takes me about  2 hours to get started

Hi! Duda from Weaviate here.
You probably doesn't have the persistence path mapped in your docker-compose.
By default, Weaviate will store data in /var/lib/weaviate
This means that you must map that path to a persistent volume in docker-compose.yaml
something like this:
    volumes:
    - ./weaviate_data/:/var/lib/weaviate

As database, it is expected that after vectorizing and ingesting your data, whenever you restart, your data should still be there.
Check our docker configurator tool for more information:
https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/installation/docker-compose#configurator
Let me know if this helps :)
